# Download attribute is not working inside the <a></a> link in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to download the pdf using "download" attribute in an `<a>` tag:

```
<a className="sl_link" href={'./myfiles/abc.pdf'}   target="_blank" download/>
```

But it is only opening in the next tab not downloading.

Comment: try to remove `target` attribute

Comment: Try `<a className="sl_link" href={require('./myfiles/abc.pdf')} target="_blank" type="application/octet-stream" download>`

Answer (score 3):

For reactjs, `download` att need value:

```
<a href={fileUrl} download={originalName}>your link</a>
```

fileUrl must be the same origin with the page

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a href="url" download="xyz.pdf">Download File</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did on my react app using typescript is as shown below

```
<a href={require('url path')} download={'File name'} > Download </a>
```

Example

```
<a href={require('../assets/doc/resume.pdf')} download={'Resume_Pdf'} > Download </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

import the file like normal in React

```
import myResume from "../../assets/myResume.pdf";
```

(you choose your own path this is just an example)

after that you just have to add the reference to you href="" and thats all.

```
<a href={myResume} download>
```

Comment: I dont get it, why did you downgrade this answear? It is correct!